# MySQL select records 1 hour ago or fresher on datetime column

Tags: php, mysql, html, database

What where clause can I use to select records that are one hour ago or fresher using a `DATETIME` timestamp?

Comment: an example of the current query your using would be good...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Something like this? I assume an `DATETIME timestamp` is an DATETIME field.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE datetimefield >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

For more information check MySQL's [date/time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Comment: The query is good, but he wants '1 hour or younger', that would be `WHERE field >= DATE_SUB...`, wouldn't it?

Comment: This returns other dates as well within the "1 Hour" not just now.